# Which one is more speed for saving some "STATIC" data? Arrays or cached db tables?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

In Symfony 3.2:

I have some data like this (as array):

```
$list1 = [
    'field-1' => ['id' => 1, 'group' => 'words', 'title' => 'Field 1'],
    'field-2' => ['id' => 2, 'group' => 'words', 'title' => 'Field 2'],
     ...
     ...
     ...
    'field-400' => ['id' => 400, 'group' => 'words', 'title' => 'Field 400'],
];

$list2 = [...];
...
$list30 = [...];
```

as you see it's about 30 arrays of 300-400 rows; but they are a **Static** array.(they wont change later)

which one of these ways are better ?

1- instruct 10 service and get every row by a method like this:

```
public function getSome($col) {
     return $this->list1[$col];
}
```

2- or insert 10 table (Entity) and cache theme (because of high speed)?

Thanx%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definite answer to this question. It depends on the exact data set, on the access patterns (how many times do you query the same value), the cache type (file or memory), maybe even on the hardware resources.

What I can suggest from experience and common sense is:

- using ORM is usually slower, even if cached
- using an external memory cache service (e.g. memcached) is usually slower than having the value in PHP memory (e.g. arrays)
- a more interesting optimization could be to re-map your structure so that you have a flat array where each key contains the whole path (e.g. $value["list1-field-1-id"])

Answer (score 1):

Create a seeder and store this data into database. Later, retrieve this data as object and use as per your requirement. Yes, you may store into cache for speeding up.

Comment: in fact there is no seeder in symfony. but it's not my prob.
my question is about speed. data in array Vs fetch from db + cache ?